# Mod_rewrite not working for some rules unless first letter capitalized? HTTPS Server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https

I've been working on this site for quite awhile. Im employing a .htaccess file to get clean URLS. This worked fine on my personal test server, which is http, and on my localhost, but after moving to the production server (with HTTPS enabled and working), some of the rules aren't working

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^index/?$  index.php [NC,L] 
  RewriteRule ^home/?$  index.php [NC,L] 
  RewriteRule ^main/?$  index.php [NC,L] 
  RewriteRule ^about/?$  about.php [NC,L] 
  RewriteRule ^music/?$  music.php [NC,L] 
  RewriteRule ^shows/?$  shows.php [NC,L] 
  RewriteRule ^blog/?$  blog.php?page=1 [NC,L] 
  RewriteRule ^blog/([\0-9]+)/?$   blog.php?page=$1   [NC,L]
  RewriteRule ^contact/?$  contact.php [NC,L] 
  RewriteRule ^profile/?$  profile.php [NC,L] 
  RewriteRule ^manage-site/?$  manage-site.php [NC,L] 
  RewriteRule ^my-blog-posts/?$  my-blog-posts.php [NC,L] 
  RewriteRule ^new-blog-post/?$    new-blog-post.php   [NC,L]
  RewriteRule ^edit-music/?$  edit-music.php [NC,L] 
  RewriteRule ^admin-login/?$    admin-login.php   [NC,L]  
  RewriteRule ^admin/?$    admin-login.php   [NC,L]  
  RewriteRule ^forgot-password/?$   forgot-password.php [NC,L]
  RewriteRule ^password-reset/?$    password-reset.php [NC,L]


  RewriteRule ^blog/article/([\w-]+)/?$   blog-post.php?slug=$1   [NC,L]  #handle requests for Individual Blog Posts
  RewriteRule ^blog/article/([\w-]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$   blog-post.php?slug=$1&reply-comment=$2   [NC,L]  #handle requests for Individual Blog Posts with a comment specified for replies when JavaScript is disabled
  RewriteRule ^password-reset/([^/]+)/?$  password-reset.php?token=$1   [NC,L] #handle requests for password-reset.php with the token included in a nicer-looking url
</IfModule>

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

Basically any of the rules that has a hyphen, i.e manage-site, gives me a 404 error UNLESS, I capitalize it, i.e Manage-site -- That works fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: don't see anything in that snippet that explains hyphen dependency or case sensitivity. possible the 404 is happening before (or after) the RewriteRule is executed. the error log usually gives additional info for a 404. rewrite logging may also provide more clues:

RewriteLog logs/rewrite.log
RewriteLogLevel 9

Comment: It looks like it's actually several pages, not just the ones with hyphens. I just only noticed on the ones with hyphens, originally. Luckily, just about every link/redirect in the site IS actually capitalized just because I find it aesthetically pleasing. Still very odd, though. 

I tried removing the ErrorDocument line, but that didn't help, other than to change back to the default apache 404 page. 

Invalid command 'RewriteLog', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

^ No luck with the rewritelog

Comment: I did notice, however: [Fri Jan 22 23:55:32.996435 2016] [negotiation:error] [pid 22241] [client 47.55.91.133:52285] AH00687: Negotiation: discovered file(s) matching request: /var/www/html/admin-login (None could be negotiated).

So the rewrite rule just flat-out isn't catching admin-login, which it should be, to rewrite it to admin-login.php

Comment: if this is Apache 2.4, rewrite logging is a little different as documented here:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging
but if this is 2.2, RewriteLog should work, just needs to be delcared in the main config:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could happen if [`MultiViews`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_negotiation.html#multiviews) (mod_negotiation) is enabled for this directory. Try disabling `MultiViews` by adding the following to the top of your .htaccess file:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

With regards to the code in the question, a scenario in which this might fail (ie. result in a 404) is when you are requesting a URL *with* a trailing slash *and* a PHP file exists with the same basename *and* `AcceptPathInfo` is `Off`. eg `example.com/main/` should otherwise rewrite to `/main.php`, but instead gets rewritten to `/main.php/` (by mod_negotiation) which results in a 404.

`MultiViews` is often enabled by default on many servers, however, a default Apache install should not have this enabled out of the box.

With `MutliViews` enabled, Apache tries to map a non-existent file with a file on the filesystem by testing various file extensions (that would return the appropriate mime-type). eg. Request `/main` (which doesn't exist) it will try `/main.php` - success. However, this runs *before* mod_rewrite, so if `MultiViews` kicks in, the mod_rewrite rule will never match.

In the scenario mentioned above, `/main/` also triggers mod_negotiation, internally rewriting the request to `/main.php/` (the trailing slash is still trailing). But if `AcceptPathInfo` is Off this will trigger a 404. This prevents mod_rewrite from rewriting the URL.

By capitalising the request, `MultiViews` fails (I assume you are on a case-sensitive OS, eg. Linux?), but since you have the `NC` flag on the `RewriteRule` this now works.

Comment: It was failing both with and without a slash, however that worked! Thanks so much. I am indeed on Ubuntu 14.04 with a LAMP stack. I can't say I understand much on what was going on but I should read up on it more on my own. Thanks a tonne!

Comment: And when it "failed", I assume that's a 404? The exact behaviour could well be dependent on other settings and the structure of your file system. For instance, if you had a directory of the same name then mod_dir is likely to kick in before (and block) mod_negotiation and automatically append a slash. However, if you are having problems rewriting requests that might be conflicting with the filesystem then it's nearly always going to be either `MultiViews` or mod_dir (`DirectorySlash`) that is the cause.